# Chemistry Equations 

Tags: equations, arrows, chemstyle

I have the following Chemistry equation:

> 2LiOH(s) + CO2(g) -> Li2CO3(s) + H2O

And I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\ce{2LiOH_{(s)} + CO_{2(g)} -> Li_{2}CO_{3(s)}+ H_{2}O_{(g)}}
```

But I can't get it to render properly. It displays like this:

[image: Equation]

Look at the arrow. What other parameters do I need?

Comment: Just a sidenote: IUPAC recommends to typeset “the states of aggregation of chemical species [...] appended to the formula in parentheses and [...] printed in Roman (upright) type without a full stop (period).” This means: _not_ as a subscript.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can you please post a [MWE](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html)? I can't reproduce your problem; the following simple code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
  \ce{2LiOH_{(s)} + CO_{2(g)} -> Li_{2}CO_{3(s)} + H_{2}O_{(g)}}
\end{document}
```

gives me:

[image]

Perhaps you are using some outdated package(s)?

Comment: Whats a MWE? I will post one if i knew what it is.

Comment: Yes i was using chemstyle so i changed to the mhchem one and thats fixed the problem thanks.

Comment: @Dean: MWE = minimal working example. I initially forgot the link but now it's added.

Comment: @Dean, Gonzalo: See also the post on meta about [minimal examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). It also links to the page in Gonzalo's answer.

Comment: Note that there should be a space before the + on the right-hand side, or the package interprets the + to indicate an ion.

Comment: @alex.jordan you're right. I've fixed the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `\rightarrow` instead of `->`, if that doesn't work.

```
\ce{2LiOH_{(s)} + CO_{2(g)} {\rightarrow} Li_{2}CO_{3(s)}+ H_{2}O_{(g)}}
```

Since you are writing chemistry, you might be interested in the command `\chemarrow` provided by the [`chemarrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chemarrow) package.

Comment: or maybe `\to`.

Comment: There are a lot of arrows :-) interesting here is that they it should be enclosed within braces to not harm the rest of the equation.

Comment: @Martin: but isn't `\to` just another name for `\rightarrow`?

Comment: @Gonzalo: Indeed it is! I didn't know that before. I would prefer it because it is 1) shorter and 2) more logical in this case, because the left side is transformed *to* the right side :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `mhchem` package is sensitive to spaces and I think the problem you were having was just due to some spaces in the wrong places.
Compare:

```
\ce{2LiOH_{(s)} + CO_{2(g)} - >Li_{2}CO_{3(s)}+ H_{2}O_{(g)}}

\ce{2LiOH_{(s)} + CO_{2(g)} -> Li_{2}CO_{3(s)} +H_{2}O_{(g)}}
```

Also it is worth noting that in this package numbers in chemical formulas are assumed to be subscripts, this saves some typing

```
\ce{2LiOH_{(s)} +CO2_{(g)} -> Li2CO3_{(s)} +H2O_{(g)}}
```